# add new column with data split from existing column using awk

Tags: sed, awk, gawk

Can this be achieved using awk?
I am looking to add a new column which has delimited data from an existing column.
My input file is a tab delimited text file.
The column with device-0, device-1 is the new column derived from phone-0-1, phone-1-2.

Input:

```
category1    phone-0-1   working     0000   0000     new     0
category1    phone-1-2   working     0000   0000     new     0
category1    phone-2-4   working     0000   0000     new     0
category1    phone-3-5   working     0000   0000     new     0
category1    phone-4-6   working     0000   0000     new     0
```

Output:

```
category1    device-0   phone-0-1    working     0000   0000     new     0
category1    device-1   phone-1-2    working     0000   0000     new     0
category1    device-2   phone-2-4    working     0000   0000     new     0
category1    device-3   phone-3-5    working     0000   0000     new     0
category1    device-4   phone-4-6    working     0000   0000     new     0
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

try this sed line, see if it works:

```
 sed 's/\sphone-[0-9]\+/&\t&/' file
```

same idea with awk:

```
awk -F'\t' -v OFS='\t' '{sub(/phone-[0-9]+/,"&\t&",$2)}7' file
```

**EDIT**, rename to device:

```
sed 's/\(\s\+\)phone-\([0-9]\+\)/\1device-\2&/' file
```

Comment: Thanks.your solution works. Sorry, I missed out a bit in my question. Is it possible to rename phone to device too? see edited question

Comment: The tab between the columns with device and phone is missing after the sed